# python - Pass by value or by reference

Tags: python, reference

I have an object with an attribute that is a list. For example:

```
obj.a = [3, 4, 5]
```

I would like to get the following behavior (but I can't manage to find a solution using magics/etc.) :

```
l = obj.a
obj.a[0] = 2

print(l) --> [3, 4, 5]
print(obj.a) ---> [2, 4, 5]
```

Of course I could simply use copy.deepcopy :

```
l = copy.deepcopy(obj.a)
```

but for several reasons I would like, somehow, to make this step automatic/hide it for my users.

[EDIT]
Using **getattribute** and returning a copy won't work of course:

```
import copy
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
         self.a = []

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if attr == 'a':
            return copy.deepcopy(super(Test, self).__getattribute__(attr))
```

Any help appreciated !

Thnak you,
Thomas

Comment: This isn't possible without explicitly copying the list during the operations when you want to be working with a copy and leaving it during operations when you don't.  In other words, from python's perspective, there is nothing different about the `obj.a` access from the first line to the second line so there is no magic signal which would allow you to hide a copy operation for some cases and not others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python)

Comment: You could override the `obj.a` property to always return a copy of the list… however, that would be rather expensive and break a lot of assumptions where you *do* expect the normal behaviour of *not* copying. Make it explicit when you need a copy, period.

Comment: Ok, thank you, this is the answer I was expecting. No magic signal then !

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to make the assignment `l = obj.a` make a copy of `obj.a`.  As deceze said in a comment, you could make `a` a property that returns a copy of the value every time you access it, but that would, well, make a copy every time you access it, not just when you assign it to `l`.  That's going to be inefficient, and probably not the behavior you want anyway

There's no way for `obj` or `obj.a` to tell the difference between something like this:

```
x = obj.a
```

and this:

```
obj.a[:2]
```

Whatever happens when you access `obj.a`, it's going to happen in both cases.  You can't "look ahead" to see whether it's going to be assigned to a variable, just to copy it in that particular case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess the behavior I wanted is close to what is called Value Class in some languages!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the following code...

```
l = list(obj.a)
```

this will allow you to copy a list to a new list

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without actually cloning the list to another list, you have to use copy() or deepcopy() depending on your requirement.